# How to get back on track of your Linux PC fails and your USB drives with Linux O.S. are lost

Tags: linux, centos, usb, iso

Assumption is you take your netbook or nettop and fly
to another country where you have no friends, etc.

You can not create a bootable usb drive with a linux iso file
unless you purchase a windows pc and then learn how to do it
using windows.

does this mean, it would only be logical to ask windows questions
on here as well in terms of how to create a bootable usb drive
with linux os via windows ?

this happened to me previously, all i could do was use unetbootin
to install linux mint on a usb drive. and then i had to install linux
mint to the blank pc, and from linux mint i had to create a centos
linux usb using the ISO file and linux mint's terminal.

creating a bootable centos usb using windows machine is not possible.
even newest fedora versions do not work.

unetbootin does not work , it only works by luck.

Comment: What is it with you and posting questions in free poem form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a bootable CentOS usb using windows is possible with http://iso2usb.sourceforge.net/